# Sizes of subfolders in hidden App Data folder

Tags: excel, vba

I want to reduce size of hidden AppData sub folders by making adjustments in large data size folders applications as I am falling short of space in drive C. To do this I searched microsoft community and in google. Some VBA code routines do not work as Permission denied message comes up. I have already done disk cleaning of the drive as a part of windows 10 feature. I just want a list of sub folders and files along with their sizes so as to take remedial steps. Manual process is very time consuming. Is there a VBA routine or function which takes due consideration of permissions on hidden folders.
Can any one help in this regard.

Comment: Please let us know which methods you've tried, and which ones do not work because of things being hidden or because of permissions.  Without these details, it's likely that you will get answers suggesting things that you've already tried.

Comment: @tehdrunksailor It will fill 5 to 6 pages if I try to mention code routines and other suggestions in microsoft community. Suffice is to mention that microsoft community generally recommends disk cleaning feature of windows 10 and permission problem comes in code line'GetDirOrFileSize = oFO.Size'. This question relates to only 'AppData' folders and its subfolder. I am easily able to get listing with size of folders and sub folders on any drive recursively.